# Dropdown menu gets hidden behind the container

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

The problem is that, whenever I click on the select dropdown, it opens behind the `<div>` after that. I tried z-index but it did not work.

```css
body {
  font: 1.5em Arial;
  background-image: url('prague2.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.top {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: Courier new;
  text-align: center;
  background: #EBA23C;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C6AEF0;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: Lucida Console;
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #F0E3CA;
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.container-inner {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: 780px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  border: dashed;
}

.bachelor {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 710px;
  margin-right: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div><br>
<ul>
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>News</a></li>
  <li><a>Czech Republic</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
      <li><a>Area</a></li>
      <li><a>Climate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Study</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>How to apply</a></li>
      <li><a>Programmes</a></li>
      <li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
      <li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Living</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a>Living costs</a></li>
      <li><a>Work</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container-inner">Why study in the Czech Republic</div><br><br>
<div class="container">These days, over 37,000 foreign students are studying in the Czech Republic; and as their universities continue to offer a ton of English-taught courses, more and more students are finding interesting options there. But if you decide to go there, you’ll
  find a large, exciting community of international students just like you. Universities in the Czech Republic also offer a wide range of programmes at the Bachelor’s, Master’s, and Ph.D level; and each university is accredited, meaning that their courses
  are recognised by companies and organisations all over the country and throughout Europe. In the Czech Republic, you can find one of the oldest traditions of higher education, dating all the way back to the 14th century. It probably also means the universities
  are haunted.</div>
<div class="container2">
  EXPERIENCE STUDYING IN THE HEART OF EUROPE
</div><br>
<div class="bachelor">Bachelor's Degrees in Czech Republic</div>
```

The problem is that, whenever I click on the select dropdown, it opens behind the  after that. I had tried z-index but it did not work.

Comment: Your example HTML is broken, all your HTML is inside the `<head>`, was this a typo? Can you use the <> icon and create a working example of your issue?

Comment: I started code 1 month ago and i don't have enough experience that's why i wrote wrong code. Can i just remove head tags ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @ParvizMuxcanov I can't edit your code as there is a pending edit awaiting approval (so maybe someone already fixed it?).

Comment: no, i am trying to change this but unfortunately doesn't work yet

Answer (score 0):

Adding this should help:

```
ul li:hover ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

**Full snippet**

```css
body {
  font: 1.5em Arial;
  background-image: url('prague2.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.top {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: Courier new;
  text-align: center;
  background: #EBA23C;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C6AEF0;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: Lucida Console;
  font-size: 22px;
  opacity: 0.8;
  background: #F0E3CA;
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.container-inner {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: 780px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  border: dashed;
}

.bachelor {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 710px;
  margin-right: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div><br>
<ul>
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li><a>News</a></li>
  <li><a>Czech Republic</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
      <li><a>Area</a></li>
      <li><a>Climate</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Study</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>How to apply</a></li>
      <li><a>Programmes</a></li>
      <li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
      <li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Living</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Arrival</a></li>
      <li><a>Living costs</a></li>
      <li><a>Work</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a>Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container-inner">Why study in the Czech Republic</div><br><br>
<div class="container">These days, over 37,000 foreign students are studying in the Czech Republic; and as their universities continue to offer a ton of English-taught courses, more and more students are finding interesting options there. But if you decide to go there, you’ll
  find a large, exciting community of international students just like you. Universities in the Czech Republic also offer a wide range of programmes at the Bachelor’s, Master’s, and Ph.D level; and each university is accredited, meaning that their courses
  are recognised by companies and organisations all over the country and throughout Europe. In the Czech Republic, you can find one of the oldest traditions of higher education, dating all the way back to the 14th century. It probably also means the universities
  are haunted.</div>
<div class="container2">
  EXPERIENCE STUDYING IN THE HEART OF EUROPE
</div><br>
<div class="bachelor">Bachelor's Degrees in Czech Republic</div>
```

Comment: Please share screenshot of what exactly is not working, and even better a second screenshot to show how it should look. The snippet above appears to be fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

remove `opacity: 0.8;` from `container`

and

add `opacity: 0.9;` in `ul li ul li`

```css
body {
  font: 1.5em Arial;
  background-image: url('prague2.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
}

.top {
  opacity: 0.8;
  font-size: 65px;
  font-family: Courier new;
  text-align: center;
  background: #EBA23C;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
  float: right;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  float: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  display: block;
}

ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #C6AEF0;
}

ul li ul li {
  display: none;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

ul li:hover ul li {
  display: block;
}

.container {
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: Lucida Console;
  font-size: 22px;
  // opacity: 0.8;
  background: #F0E3CA;
  float: left;
  width: 450px;
  height: 630px;
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.container-inner {
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #F05050;
  text-align: center;
  width: 450px;
  height: 40px;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.container2 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 650px;
  margin-left: 780px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: Courier New;
  opacity: 0.7;
  text-align: center;
  border: dashed;
}

.bachelor {
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 2px solid;
  width: 800px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: 710px;
  margin-right: 650px;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0.6;
  font-family: Courier New;
  font-style: bold;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">

<head>
  <title>Home page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <div class="top">Study in Czech Republic</div><br>
  <ul>
    <li><a>Home</a></li>
    <li><a>News</a></li>
    <li><a>Czech Republic</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Facts and figures</a></li>
        <li><a>Area</a></li>
        <li><a>Climate</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Study</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>How to apply</a></li>
        <li><a>Programmes</a></li>
        <li><a>Scholarships</a></li>
        <li><a>Tuition fees</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Living</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Arrival</a></li>
        <li><a>Living costs</a></li>
        <li><a>Work</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a>Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container-inner">Why study in the Czech Republic</div><br><br>
  <div class="container">These days, over 37,000 foreign students are studying in the Czech Republic; and as their universities continue to offer a ton of English-taught courses, more and more students are finding interesting options there. But if you decide to go there, you’ll
    find a large, exciting community of international students just like you.
```

Comment: what not work see in `snippet output` its properly work

Comment: In snippet output it does not show the background picture and containers on the center

Comment: That's because they're linked to your local file system and not hosted.

Comment: but your question is `drop down menu hide` and i solve that problem if othore problem in  your code so you manually check your drop down menu problem solve @ParvizMuxcanov

Comment: Thank you so much !